# Git : a commit that stands alone

Tags: git

I found a commit in my tree that stands strictly alone : no parents, no children. I stumbled upon it because I noticed it was appearing in all my `log -S/-G` searches. And indeed, since it stands alone, in order to describe the state of things at this commit, it contains the whole world - instead of a diff to a parent like in the normal case. So everything in my system is referenced specifically in this commit, and thus found in searches.

Also I found another commit with the exact same commit message from around the same time. The diff between the two is very small and has no meaningful content - mostly cosmetic blanks lines here and there. This commit is well integrated in the tree.

The commit that stands alone is also the one to which a remote branch points. Maybe that's why it's still advertised, despite whatever happened to it that left it to stand entirely alone.

1. Can I force the branch to go to the other, more meaningful commit, and thus forget about that stand-alone one ?
2. How could this ever happen ? Is there any good practice I could follow to prevent this from happening again ?

Comment: It's a root commit. Every repository has at least one root commit. Imagin that you initialize a new Git repository and make the first commit. That's a root commit.

Comment: _"it contains the whole world - instead of a diff to a parent like in the normal case"_ -- the Git commits contain the entire work tree at the moment of the commit, not just diffs.

Comment: Root means children are possible - no ? Here it has none. Also my repo does have a root commit, with no parents - but with every other commit except this one being its child. Why another one ?

Comment: A Git repository may have as many root commits one likes and there are several different ways to achieve that. Usually it has only one commit because having multiple root commits is not useful.

Comment: @axiac Okay but then why does this stand-alone commit appear in all my searches, and not all the others ? Especially, that other commit whose diff to the stand-alone one is minimal doesn't appear in searches that are not expected to match it - so it behaves normally. Something about contents of the stand-alone commit is special.

Comment: For a commit, if it does not have any parent, then it won't have any parent. If it does not have any child, it's just because you haven't made another commit based on it. You can make as many commits as you want based on it.

Comment: But so this all means that the author of the commit somehow went through the trouble of recommitting everything as a new indepedent root by accident ? Is it so easy to do that accidents are in fact not entirely improbable ?

Comment: Looks like an artifact produced by erroneous commands, like many repos have. Someone might have used `git checkout --detach` and commited the result, or another combination of commands. The fact that it has no children is, as @ElpieKay mentioned, unsurprising and unremarkable.

Comment: A commit that is reachable is never deleted. The reachable commits are the commits that are pointed by (local or remote) branches, the commits that have tags on them, the commits that can be reached from other reachable commits by walking the history (going to parents) and the commits that are listed in a branch reflog. You say that your rogue commit is pointed by a remote branch. That is the reason why it is still present and it can still be found by certain `git log` operations. Remove the remote branch (or move it to another commit) and the rogue commit won't appear in listings any more.

Comment: _"the author of the commit somehow went through the trouble of recommitting everything as a new indepedent root by accident"_ -- Let's say that you just created the first commit of your repo. It is the root commit, it does not have parents. If you run `git commit --amend` you get a new commit that also has no parents. This one is the new root commit but the old one still exists in the repo and it is still accessible as long as it is pointed by a branch, for example.

Comment: Take a look at the documentation of [`git gc`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-gc). The first paragraph of the [**Notes** section](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-gc#_notes) explains why that commit is still present in your repo. I cannot tell you why it appears in the results of `git log` but there is an explanation for that, for sure.

Comment: Forcing the remote branch to point to the better-integrated commit rather than to the stand-alone one made it disappear from searches. Garbage cleaning/pruning will probably later remove it, which is fine.

Comment: @RomainValeri `git checkout --detatch` will not create parent-less commits. It makes a normal commit with a parent. It just doesn't update any branch to point to the newly created commit. Maybe you're confusing it with `git checkout --orphan` and then committing, which will make a parent-less commit.

Comment: @Alderath Oh you're perfectly right. Confusion on my part, thanks for the correction. Definitely `--orphan` I was trying to refer to.